# Getting the normal of a cone - Raytracing

Tags: c, debugging, raytracing, normals

I'm writing a raytracer in C and I'm having trouble perfecting the shadows on my cone. I think the problem I have is in the calculation of the normal of the cone at the intersection point. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niluy.png) is a rendering of what I currently have.

The scene described as follows:

```
resolution: 500, 500
scene:
{
    light:
    {
        position: 0, -10, -40
        intensity: 20000
        color: white
    }
    camera:
    {
        position: -5, -7, -40
        direction: 0, 0, 1
        fov: 50
    }
    plane: 
    {
        position: 0, 0, 0
        direction: 0, 0, 1
        color: white
    }
    cone:
    {
        position: 0, 0, -2.5
        direction: -5, -8, 0
        color: white
        radius: 5
        height: 20
    }
    cylinder:
    {
        position: 10, 0, 0
        direction: -5, -8, 0
        color: white
        radius: 5
        height: 20
    }
}
```

Note that the light is between the objects and the camera.
The issue there is that I think the cone should be more illuminated, at least, in some areas, as illuminated as the cylinder to the right.

I calculated the normal based on [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792861/surface-normal-to-a-cone) as follows:

```
static void get_cone_normal(t_raytracing_tools *r, t_ray *ray, t_object *obj)
{
    //nhit is the normal at hit point.
    ray->nhit.x = (ray->hit.x - obj->pos.x) * (obj->height / obj->rad);
    ray->nhit.y = obj->rad / obj->height;
    ray->nhit.z = (ray->hit.z - obj->pos.z) * (obj->height / obj->rad);
    ray->nhit = v_norm(ray->nhit);
}
```

I also thought of the direction of the normal depending on what side of the cone is hit by the ray. After I solve the quadratic equation and get two potential answers, I test each one to figure out if it is within my finite cone (parametric equation is for infinite cone) and according to how the ray hits the cone, I have an int variable n_dir which is either 1 or -1 which I use to invert the normal if the ray hits the inside of the cone. Here is the code for that part:

```
 bool       get_finite_cone_intersection(t_raytracing_tools *r, t_ray *ray, t_object *obj, t_intersection_tools *i)
{
    bool    r1_too_low;
    bool    r1_too_high;
    bool    r2_too_low;
    bool    r2_too_high;

    //i->r1 and i->r2 are the two roots (solutions of quadratic eq.)
    r1_too_low = lower_than_min(i->r1, i, obj, ray);
    r1_too_high = higher_than_max(i->r1, i, obj, ray);
    r2_too_low = lower_than_min(i->r2, i, obj, ray);
    r2_too_high = higher_than_max(i->r2, i, obj, ray);
    if (r1_too_low)
    {
        i->r1 = NAN; //I set roots to NAN if they are not valid solutions
        if (r2_too_low || r2_too_high)
            i->r2 = NAN;
        else
            i->n_dir = 1;
    }
    else if (r1_too_high)
    {
        i->r1 = NAN;
        if (r2_too_low || r2_too_high)
            i->r2 = NAN;
        else
            i->n_dir = -1;
    }
    else if (!r1_too_low && !r1_too_high)
    {
        i->r2 = NAN;
        if (r2_too_low)
            i->n_dir = -1;
        else
            i->n_dir = 1;
    }
    return (true);
}

bool        lower_than_min(double r, t_intersection_tools *i, t_object *obj, t_ray *ray)
{
    if (r > 0)
    {
        if (v_dot(obj->dir, v_sub(v_add(ray->origin, v_scale(ray->dir, r)), obj->pos)) < 0.0)
            return (true);      
    }
    return (false);
}
bool        higher_than_max(double r, t_intersection_tools *i, t_object *obj, t_ray *ray)
{
    if (r > 0)
    {
        if (v_dot(obj->dir, v_sub(v_add(ray->origin, v_scale(ray->dir, r)),
            v_add(obj->pos, v_scale(obj->dir, obj->height)))) > 0.0)
            return (true);      
    }
    return (false);
}
```

Also, what the heck, here's the code for my cone intersection:

```
    bool        get_cone_intersection(t_raytracing_tools *r, t_ray *ray, t_object *cone)
{
    t_intersection_tools i;
    t_vec3    ori_cen;
    double    k;
    int         n_dir;

    i.n_dir = 1;
    k = tan(cone->angle);
    ori_cen = v_sub(ray->origin, cone->pos);
    i.q.x = v_dot(ray->dir, ray->dir) - (1.0 + k * k) * powf(v_dot(ray->dir, cone->dir), 2.0);
    i.q.y = 2 * (v_dot(ray->dir, ori_cen) - (1.0 + k * k) * v_dot(ray->dir, cone->dir)
                * v_dot(ori_cen, cone->dir));
    i.q.z = v_dot(ori_cen, ori_cen) - (1.0 + k * k) * powf(v_dot(ori_cen,
                cone->dir), 2.0);
    if (!solve_quadratic(i.q, &i.r1, &i.r2))
        return (0);
    (i.r2 < i.r1) ? ft_swapd(&i.r1, &i.r2) : 0;
    get_finite_cone_intersection(r, ray, cone, &i);
    if (i.r1 < 0 || isnan(i.r1)) //the smallest one is negative, thus take the other one
    {
        i.r1 = i.r2;
    }
    if (i.r1 < 0 || isnan(i.r1))    
        return (false);
    if (r->t > i.r1)
    {
        ray->t = i.r1;
        if (ray->type == R_PRIMARY)
        {
            ray->hit_obj = cone;
            ray->hit_type = T_CONE;
            ray->n_dir = i.n_dir;
        }
    }
    return (true);
}
```

Hope that's not too much info at once! Again, would love it if someone could shed some light (haha) on the situation.

Comment: Types missing. Post structure definitions.   Is `.rad ` a FP number?  Is `obj->height / obj->rad` done with integer math?

Comment: obj->rad is the radius of the object. Height and radius are doubles.

Comment: Without posting structures def, reviewers are obliged to analyze code by sight, rather than also employing compilers and other tools - making it unnecessarily harder to assist.  Post enough code so we may compile it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to stackoverflow. Here's a link to my github repo. Hope this helps: https://github.com/JanWalsh91/RTv1

Comment: Post relevant code here is better, not at some other site.