# Find cone normal

Tags: c, math, graphics, raytracing

I am actually making a raytracer in c. I need to find the normal of a cone depending of the hitpoint. My function is prototyped like so :

`t_vec_3    cone_normal(t_point hitpoint, t_cone cone);`

the cone struct contain these informations :

```
struct    s_cone
{
    t_point    coordinate;
    t_vec_3    vector;
    double    diameter;
    double    height;
    t_color    color;
    t_material    material;
};
```

I've tried several solutions, but in all cases they only work if the cone vector is equal to (0, 1, 0).

my function currently looks like this, but it only works if the cone is straight.

```
t_vec_3    cone_normal(t_point hitpoint, t_cone cone)
{
    t_vec_3    tmp;
    t_vec_3    result;

    tmp = set_vec(hitpoint.x - cone.coordinate.x, 0, hitpoint.z - cone.coordinate.z);
    calculate_norm(&tmp);
    tmp.x/= tmp.norme;
    tmp.z/= tmp.norme;
    normalize_vec(&tmp);
    result = set_vec(tmp.x * cone.height / (cone.diameter / 2), \
    (cone.diameter / 2) / cone.height, tmp.z * cone.height / (cone.diameter / 2));
    normalize_vec(&result);
    return (result);
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to specify the calculate_norm and normalize_vec code.

```
double  calculate_norm(t_vec_3 *vec)
{
    double  norm;

    norm = sqrt(pow(vec->x, 2) + pow(vec->y, 2) + pow(vec->z, 2));
    vec->norme = norm;
    return (norm);
}

void    normalize_vec(t_vec_3 *vec)
{
    double  norm;

    norm = calculate_norm(vec);
    vec->x = vec->x / norm;
    vec->y = vec->y / norm;
    vec->z = vec->z / norm;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [surface normal to a cone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792861/surface-normal-to-a-cone)

Answer (score 0):

You know the cone.height and cone.diameter so you know the angle at the apex (from side to axis).

```
tan(apexangle) = cone.diameter / (2*cone.height)
```

Once you have the unit vectors ihat and jhat that point in the direction of the axis to the hitpoint and along the axis respectively, then the unit normal nhat must be

```
nhat = ihat * cos(apexangle) + jhat * sin(apexangle)
```

You can do it with just one trig calculation by dividing through by cos

```
nhat * sec(apexangle) = ihat + jhat * (cone.diameter / (2*cone.height))
```

jhat is just your normalised cone.vector (I assume), and ihat is normalised

```
(hitpoint - cone.coordinate)- ((hitpoint - cone.coordinate).jhat)jhat.
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand exactly what "ihat" "jhat" and "nhat" correspond to. And I don't understand where to implement this in my function.

Comment: @coromo They are unit vectors, I guess.

Comment: I assumed vector pointed from the base to the apex (opposite way round to Spektre's answer). If it's the other way around then jhat is normalised -cone.vector.

Answer (score 0):

I see it like this:

[image: cone]

`p0` is cone position, `t` is central axis unit vector, `p` is your hit point on surface and `n` is unknown normal. You can exploit cross product:

```cpp
q = dot(t,p-p0);                                     // distance of p projected onto central axis and p0
     if (q<=0.0) n=-t;                               // special case hit point is equal to p0
else if (q>=cone_height) n=+t;                       // special case hit point is on base of cone
else n = (+/-) normalize(cross(cross(t,p-p0),p-p0)); // normal case
```

The `(+/-)` sign just decide if the normal point outwards or inwards too lazy to evaluate if it should be + or -  so in case normals points inwards just negate or swap operands in one of the cross products...

Comment: I've tried to implement what you've explained but it doesn't work. on the cone it's as if there were no light

Comment: @coromo that is most likely just normal pointing the other way than your lighting expects so just negate the normal for the normal case:  `n = - normalize(cross(cross(t,p-p0),p-p0));` or use double sided lighting ... if it makes any difference. If it still does not work try to render the normal `n` along with `p,p0,t` just to see if the input is also OK

Comment: see [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) look at the debug render you could try to do something similar ...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to find the normal one, I won't explain the code precisely but here's how I did it

```
t_vec_3 cone_normal(t_ray camray, t_point hitpoint, t_cone cone)
{
    double  k;
    double  scalar;
    t_vec_3 result;
    t_vec_3 tmp;

    k = tan((cone.diameter / 2) * M_PI / 180.0);
    tmp = set_vec(camray.origin.x - cone.coordinate.x, camray.origin.y - \
        cone.coordinate.y, camray.origin.z - cone.coordinate.z);
    scalar = scalar_product(camray.direction, set_vec(hitpoint.x, hitpoint.y, \
        hitpoint.z)) + scalar_product(tmp, cone.vector);
    tmp = set_vec(hitpoint.x + camray.origin.x, hitpoint.y + camray.origin.y, \
        hitpoint.z + camray.origin.z);
    result = minus_vec(minus_vec(tmp, set_vec(cone.coordinate.x, \
        cone.coordinate.y, cone.coordinate.z)), multip_vec(cone.vector, \
        ((1 + pow(k, 2.0))) * scalar));
    normalize_vec(&result);
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: A comment explaining what each method does can help everyone in the community that reads your solution